# load 16-bit data from table in 8051 without modifying DPTR

Tags: optimization, lookup-tables, 8051, 16-bit, accumulator

I'm trying to make a simple routine for the 8051 processor that allows me to load any 16-bit number of my choice from a table stored in code memory without modifying any part of DPTR and without requiring stack space. So push and pop cannot be used. Also, I want to use the least amount of processing time possible.

So far I came up with the following code that sort-of allows me to load a value from a table of 4 16-bit values to accumulator and R2 where R2 has the high byte and A has the low byte.

Is this the most efficient way to do this? If so, how do I calculate how much to add to the accumulator before each movc instruction in this example?

```
  mov A,#2h         ;want 2nd entry from table
  acall getpointer  ;run function below
                    ;here R2:A should form correct 16-bit pointer ( = 0456h)
  END

  getpointer:
      rl A                ;multiply A value * 2
      mov R2,A            ;copy to R2
      inc R2              ;R2=A+1
                          ;add something to A but what?
      movc A,@A+PC        ;Load first byte
      xch A,R2            ;put result in R2 and let A=original A+1
                          ;add something to A again but what?
      movc A,@A+PC        ;load second byte
  ret                   ;keep result in A and exit
  mytable: 
      dw 0123h
      dw 0456h
      dw 0789h
      dw 0000h
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getpointer:
    rl  a
    mov r2, a
    add a, #5   ; skip all insts after 1st movc and 1 byte
    movc    a, @a+pc
    xch a, r2   ; 1-byte
    inc a   ; 1-byte ; skip all instrs after 2nd movc
    movc    a, @a+pc ; 1-byte
    ret     ; 1-byte
mytable:
    ...
```

I hope I got it right. Note that `movc a, @a+pc` first increments `pc`, then adds `a` to this incremented value. This is why I added instruction lengths in the comments, to show how much code there is.

Note that index of 2 corresponds to `0789h`, not `0456h`.

Also note that you may need to swap `a` and `r2` and the cheapest may be to swap the data within the table.